# How to read value from DockerFile to client side?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, next.js

I am using nextJs framework with reactJs. I have docker file mentioning `ENV FLAG=ONE`. I need it in client side to show design on basis of that `FLAG` value `ONE` or `TWO`. Also, using Node. I tried hard, `ENV NODE_APP` value `production` is available using **next.config.js** and `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix but I am not getting `FLAG` value?

Comment: Are you sure your env variable is properly added? Are you able to get this value server-side? Could you also please share your client code?